# Simplest uniform semilattice $C_{\omega}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $C_{\omega} = \{ e_0, e_1, e_2, \cdots \}$ with
$$e_0 > e_1 > e_2 > \cdots > e_n > e_{n+1} > \cdots$$
form a semilattice.

We know that $C_{\omega}$ form a commutative semigroup under the binary operation 
$$ e_i \cdot e_j = e_i \; \; \text{iff} \; i \leq j. $$

- A subset $I \subset S$, where $S$ is a semigroup is said to be an ideal of $S$ if $SI \subseteq I$ and $IS \subseteq I$.
- The principal ideal generated by $e_k$ is of the form $C_{\omega}e_k = \{ e_k, e_{k+1}, \cdots \}$
- I know that for each $m, n \in \mathbb N$, there is an isomorphism between $C_{\omega}e_n$ and $C_{\omega}e_m$ which is 
  $$ \tau_{n,m} : C_{\omega}e_n  \rightarrow C_{\omega}e_m$$ 
  defined by $e_k \tau_{n,m} = e_{k-n+m}$ for all $k \geq n$.

  My Question is :

> > How to show that there is no isomorphism between $C_{\omega}e_n$ and $C_{\omega}e_m$ other than $\tau_{n,m}$.

Comment: I am confused. If $e_i \cdot e_j = e_i $ iff $ i \leq j$, one gets in particular $e_n \cdot e_k = e_{\min\{n,k\}} $ and hence $C_{\omega}e_k = \{ e_k, e_{k-1}, \cdots, e_0 \}$, right?

Comment: @J.-Pin: You are right, product of two element is $e_i \cdot e_j = \text{min}\{e_i, e_j\}$ in place  min$\{i,j\}$. Sorry for this, i am editing.  I did it by contradiction.